# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (2,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Tengo este código

```
xfit = np.linspace(-1, 3.5)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=50, cmap='autumn')
plt.plot([0.6], [2,1], 'x', color='red', markeredgewidth=2, markersize=10)

for m, b in [(1, 0.70), (0.5, 1.6), (-0.2, 2.9)]:
    plt.plot(xfit, m * xfit + b, '-k')

plt.xlim(-1, 3.5);
```

Y me tira este error

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (2,)

Comment: y cual es la matriz? o el objeto `numpy`, que estas tratando de hacer?, por favor añade mas detalles a tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

El error en la línea `plt.scatter`
se puede explicar simplemente con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
x = [1,] # dimension == 1
y = [1, 4] # dimension == 2
plt.plot(x, y)
```

> ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (2,)

Mira lo que te da:

```
print(X[:, 0])
print(X[:, 1])
```